# Init 3 command with systemd

Tags: centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, systemd, init

I am using Oracle Linux 7 for test purposes. I understand that the entire RHEL family (RHEL, CentOS, and OL) is using `systemd` now.

As far as I know with `systemd` instead of `init 3` I should use `systemctl isolate multi-user.target` however I tried both on OL7 and both works.

What I want to know is why the `init 3` command still work? Is this expected with `systemd` or the RHEL family implemented some kind of backward compatibility feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Systemd Service & Resource Management in Red Hat Enterprise Linux](https://sysadmincorner.wordpress.com/category/linux/system-startup/), /sbin/init is now a symbolic link to /usr/lib/systemd/systemd.

The runlevel and telinit commands are still available in the system and work as expected, but are only included for compatibility reasons and should be avoided.

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 is distributed with a number of predefined targets that are more or less similar to the standard set of runlevels from the previous releases of this system. For compatibility reasons, it also provides aliases for these targets that directly map them to SysV runlevels.

From [WORKING WITH SYSTEMD TARGETS](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Targets.html)